# Having trouble setting library version to stable

Tags: google-apps-script, shared-libraries

I've created a library for use in another apps script, and looking at the Manifest's docs on Google, it says you can set the "version" in the "libraries" section to "stable" if you want it to automatically use the latest available verison

> dependencies.libraries[].version   string
>
> > The version of the library that is used by the script. This is either a version number or stable, meaning the last version created.

In my manifest I have this (with [name] and [ID] filled in):

```
"dependencies": {
"libraries": [{
  "userSymbol": "[name]",
  "libraryId": "[ID]",
  "version": "stable",
  "developmentMode": false
}]}
```

However, if I set this and try to view the web app, it gives me:

> "Sorry, unable to open the file at this time"

Changing the version back to a number fixes this. Am I not setting this correctly?

Comment: I think you're using it right. It's an error in the documentation. You can try to use number for a while. You can also log an issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com).

Comment: Thanks, I've logged it!