# Can one iterate through bound scripts and edit their manifest files via a script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am building an application that will have many users, each of whom will have many Google documents. Each doc will have a custom menu and that custom menu will invoke a library script. I may need or want to change the coding in that library script from time to time.

As changes to a library script must be "saved" as a new version in order for the changed version to be passed on to client scripts (in my case, the scripts bound to Google Docs), I need a way that users can "batch" update the version number in their docs' bound script appsscript.json
file.

I have researched this issue and there seems to be two general alternatives: set the client scripts' library mode to "Developmental" or use an add-on.

The problem with the former is that it won't work unless the users are all granted edit mode access to the library script (which seems particularly a bad idea as the users may well not even be known to me).

The problem with the later is essentially complication and cost. If I make the add-on private, it only works for users in the same domain which means I have to create a G-Suite domain (and pay at least (as of this writing) $72 per year per user—a non-starter for this project).

If I make the add-on public, in addition to the complication, I have to sign up to the Google Cloud Platform and the costs for that require one to navigate a veritable maze of choices and alternatives such that at this point, I really have no idea what the cost per service or user would be.

Below I present some "mock-up" code that should at least indicate the direction I am trying to go.

```
function upDate() {
  var version = 23
  var scripts = "https://script.google.com/u/0/home"
          //while (scripts.hasNext()) {
            //var script = files.next();
  //Note: All of the script's have the same name as they commence life bound to a template, which template is duplicated to create the rest of the user's docs
  if( scriptName = ScriptName){
            //set.dependencies.enabledAdvancedServices[].version
}
}
```

I don't even know if it's possible to step through bound scripts the way one step's through files in a Google Drive, so that is the first question. Then, the second question is whether, assuming you can step through the scripts one by one, you can change a manifest value—in this case, the version number.

Comment: I thought I might have found a workaround to this. On the Google Apps Script documentation on Manifests [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests#editing_a_manifest], there is this statement: "`dependencies.libraries[].version`  `string`  The version of the library that is used by the script. This is either a version number or stable, meaning the last version created." I tried that and the bound script (which creates a menu on a Google Doc) failed to appear in the doc.

Comment: When I take "stable" out and put the correct version number back in, the menu appears. This SO post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53091790/having-trouble-setting-library-version-to-stable] indicates that the foregoing "stable" documentation is erroneous. Any one have any further info on this?

Comment: The bug report is here: [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118784705]

Comment: More bad news: from [https://mashe.hawksey.info/2017/11/everything-you-always-wanted-to-know-about-google-apps-script-manifest-files-but-were-afraid-to-ask/#Managing_manifest_files_with_ManifestApp] "Note: This only works on standalone scripts (container bound are not accessible)."

Comment: This SO post [https://script.google.com/d/1Tsq8dhMImTN8GWoTHB9DpnJG22x1Af52Jzpj2XoNppmOAJOUZy3gjtwu/edit] shows one can programmatically edit a script's manifest file, but as the comment immediately above notes, not container bound scripts.

Comment: Container bound scripts can be modified using the Apps Script API.  I do it all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One cannot step through container-bound scripts as they are (no longer) located in one's Google Drive. Moreover, despite Google's documentation about using a "stable" value in the version section of the manifest, that documentation appears erroneous. Finally, one cannot programmatically edit standalone scripts.

However, there is a workaround. What I ended up doing was writing a script that steps through all of the involved Google Docs and copies them to a blank template (i.e., in effect, duplicates them all). That blank template has the bound script installed in it with the new version number of the library. Then, delete original docs (via the same script) and *voilà*, batch update to all of the target docs is accomplished. (One drawback of this is: if Google Doc revision history is important to you, be advised this gambit jettisons that (unless you keep the original versions).